# Developing a matplotlib surface from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data structure which is generated from the following (where [a] func1 and func2 are placeholder functions and [b] i1, etc. are placeholder variable values):

```
def func1(x,y,z):
    return x+y/z

def func2(x,y,z):
    return x/y+z

var1 = [i1, i2, ..., i]
var2 = [j1, j2, ..., j]
var3 = [k1, k2, ..., k]

data_bin = {}

for i in var1:
    data_bin[i] = {}

    for j in var2:
        data_bin[i][j] = {}

        for k in var3:
            data_bin[i][j][k] = [func1(i,j,k), func2(i,j,k)]
```

Which yields a data structure like so:

```
{i1 : {j1 : {k1 : [func1_val, func2_val], ...}, ...}, ...}
```

And I am trying to create plots like so (pseudocode)

```
for given i1:
    x-axis = j
    y-axis = k
    z-axis = func1_val
```

or

```
for given k1:
    x-axis = i
    y-axis = j
    z-axis = func2_val
```

How do I go about looping through the dictionary in order to extract these values into working bins to use in matplotlib or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered saving the data in a numpy array?

Comment: I've not, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of doing a matplotlib plot is with the data stored in a numpy array.

In this case for exemple you can define a meshgrid:

```
mesh1, mesh2, mesh3 = np.meshgrid(var1, var2, var3)
```

Which will define 3 3d arrays that can esily be used as input to a matplotlib surface plot.

Then, the function can be calles without loops, and the operations will be performed elementwise directly. i.e.

```
res1 = func1(mesh1,  mesh2, mesh3)
```

And eventually do the plots with a code similar to this pseudocode:

```
for i in var1:
    plt.plot_surface(mesh2[i,:,:], mesh3[i,:,:], res1[i,:,:])
```

In the case of very large arrays however, creating a 3d meshgrid can be too memory consuming. Therefore, it may be a better idea to build 2d meshgrids and loop over the third. One example of this would be:

```
mesh2, mesh3 = np.meshgrid(var2, var3) # it can be defined outside because only var1 varies during the loop
for i in var1:
    res1 = func1(i,mesh2,mesh3)
    plt.plot_surface(mesh2, mesh3, res1)
```